# What is the domain of $y = (-2)^x\;?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

What is the domain of $y = (-2)^x\;?$

- I searched it on Wolfram, and it said it doesn't have a domain.
- But does it not exist for all integer values?

Comment: Do you think it should be possible to "infer" the domain from a formula of the type $y$ equals "something with $x$"? It depends. Do we use complex numbers here, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we can define $a^x$ *as a real number* and for $a < 0$ as long as $x$ is rational and has odd denominator. This includes integers (denominator $1$). For example,
$$
(-2)^{5} = -32 \\
(-2)^{5/3} = \sqrt[3]{-32} = -\sqrt[3]{32} \\
(-2)^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{4}.
$$
This exponentiation satisfies all the right properties, for instance:

- $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ ($b$ and $c$ must have odd denominator)
- $a^{b+c} = a^b a^c$ ($b$ and $c$ must have odd denomiator)

We run into problems if we ever have something with even denominator. For example,
$$
(-2)^{2 \cdot \frac12} = (-2)^1 = -2,
$$
but
$$
\left((-2)^2\right)^{\frac12} = 4^{\frac12} = 2, 
$$
so $(a^b)^c \ne a^{bc}$ when we have even denominators.

---

So that we don't have to worry about the even denominator problem, it may be preferable in many cases to leave $a^x$ only for $a > 0$.

Alternatively, sometimes we define $a^x$ for $a < 0$ as a **complex number** by writing $-1$ as $e^{k \pi x}$ for an odd $k$. Let me give an example: $-2 = 2e^{i\pi}$, so we can define
$$
(-2)^x := 2e^{i\pi x}.
$$
This will give the expected answer for integer values of $x$, but for other rational $x$ with negative denominator, it will **not** agree with the definition I gave before.
The problem with doing this is that we are just picking out one answer arbitrarily (one value of $k$). We could have said $-2 = e^{-i\pi x}$ instead, or $-2 = e^{3\pi x}$, and we would have gotten a different answer.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\;(-2)^x\;$ is defined as long as $\;x\;$ is not of the form $\;\frac m{2n}\;,\;\;m,n\in\Bbb N\;$ . Since in any non-trivial interval there are lots of numbers of this kind (in fact, infinitely many), it'd be really nasty to even begin to try to describe the domain of this thing, not to mention that it wouldn't be open, connected and some other things that are usually required for domains of real functions.

Comment: You mean for _rational_ $x$ not on the form mentioned? And $m$ odd?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes. Usually fractions are written in reduced form, but the question is in place.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha (mentioned by the asker) will evaluate things like `(-2)^Pi` (i.e. $2^\pi$). It uses some convention of a principal value of the complex exponentiation function.  What the domain is cannot be inferred from a formula alone.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I don't know if you're addressing me, and if you are then I don't know why. I guess WA and many other programs can do weird stuff (and have quite a few bugs in several branches of mathematics). For me, for example, in complex analysis it'd be $$(-2)^\pi=e^{\pi\text{Log}(-2)}=e^{\pi\left(\log 2+i\arg(-2)\right)}$$ where I'd probably choose the branch $\;[0,\infty)\;$ and thus $\;\arg(-2)=\pi\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, so $x=\pi $ is in the domain of the map $x\mapsto (-2)^x $ even though  $\pi $ is not rational? You just told what the value is.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Nop. There is no **the** value here, as most probably you know. I only pointed out *a* value. Anyway, as remarked in my answer, this thing (wannabee function) may not have a domain . Anyway, that $\;(-2)^\pi\;$ doesn't contradict, I believe, what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, but not such as continous functions this is more like a sequence $\{(-2)^{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\begin{cases}
(2^n)\mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is even}.\\
-(2^n)\mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is odd}.\end{cases}$

and for the negative integeers you can use the exponent's law.